# Visual flow to send out an email to the Selected users from a Multi-select picklist?

Tags: email, email-alert, multi-select, visual-flows

Is it possible to send out an email via Visual flows where I have the capability to Select/deselect users(Multi-Select picklist of users)?
The users would be **Customer Community User** licensed users.

I know I can have the flexibility to make my on-the-go subject/body.

Also can I have a single folder/group of users that is displayed as the one of the Multi-select picklist values?

Comment: Have you tried implementing this using Apex/VF pages?